# USB switch for monitors

Tags: usb, hdmi, displays, switch, usb-c

I have a notebook PC with 2 micro-USB Type C ports and no other video output, and a PC with DVI and HDMI.

I have two other monitors, both of them have HDMI, DVI, and VGA ports, and if I recall correctly, DisplayPort as well.

Finally I have a USB keyboard and mouse.

I would like to buy some device that will be connected to all monitors and to the USB mouse / keyboard, and that will allow me to use both computers with the same keyboard / mouse, selecting witch monitor to use (also both) for each specific computer.

Any advice?

Comment: I know you posted in Hardware recommendations, but there are also software solutions, which will work even with different OS. Interested? https://symless.com/synergy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Workstation**

The cheap route is to use a [USB-C Hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GDHD3VC). I have used this one across many devices and can vouch for it.

The fancy way, you can get a [USB-C Dock](https://smile.amazon.com/CalDigit-TS3-Plus-Thunderbolt-Dock/dp/B07CZPV8DF) that is basically the same thing but is meant to be stationary, so has its own power supply and more functionality.

Both of the above options would turn your desk into a generic "Work Station" at which you could sit down with any USB-C device and connect to all your peripherals.

**KVM**

If you want to have both computers at the same desk always on and easily swap back and forth, you are looking for a KVM (Keyboard Video Mouse). Unfortunately, USB-C is relatively new and I do not know of any that run directly from USB-C yet available.

There are may kinds of KVMs available. Some [split video cables](https://smile.amazon.com/CKL-Monitor-Extended-Display-CKL-922HUA/dp/B07KVJ54X2), some [split USB connections](https://smile.amazon.com/Selector-ABLEWE-Switcher-Peripheral-One-Button/dp/B07TS5JNT3), and others that [split both separately](https://smile.amazon.com/Supports-Control-Computers-Servers-DVR-HDMI/dp/B07SGX5D2G).  You could convert from USB-C to USB-A and then go to one of these.

**What to look for**

[USB-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C) is the connection and is part of [Thunderbolt 3](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/consumer/) but the two are [not the same](https://www.howtogeek.com/449991/thunderbolt-3-vs.-usb-c-whats-the-difference/).

You can charge many devices through the same port you connect to the hub. The first device I listed has this functionality, known as power pass-through. Often sold with the [Power Delivery (PD)](https://www.usb.org/usb-charger-pd) mark followed by the power rating for that device.

If you are going to use one computer on each monitor and want to share a mouse and keyboard, you can use software like [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy). It's a great software that I have used many times.

**Note**

There are several very similar questions on this site and no perfect answers. It's a messy area to search for, but once you know what your looking for you can find the solution that works best for you.

**Edit: Answer to comment**

For keyboard and mouse, there will be absolutely no problem going to USB-A. The only problem is that you said your computer only has USB-C outputs and no video output. I would recommend going from laptop to [this cheaper hub](https://smile.amazon.com/Anker-Adapter-Ethernet-MacBook-ChromeBook/dp/B071G83L1J) and then from this hub's HDMI and USB-A to the above linked KVM. Use the first Hub I linked in the exact same way if you also want power pass-through.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So as far as I understand the link that should fit the requirements I provide should be the  one on "split both separately". The only doubt is about the USB-C to USB-A converter. Would there be any problems in your opinion?

Comment: great reply again, thank you very much for your info. It was really really clarifying

Comment: one last thing. I have already a usb-c to usb-A hub. Do you think it would be possible to just buy a Usb-A to Hdmi converter and connect that in the hub?

Comment: Yes. They even have cables that go from USB-C to HDMI. Do you have another way to charge the laptop if you use both plugs?

Comment: I'm afraid not. From the spec I have : 2 USB TypeC 3.1 Gen 2 (Thunderbolt 3, DP 1.2, PD 3.0, data transfer, HP Sleep and Charge)
1 USB 3.1 Gen 2

Comment: Then you'll want to either use one port for charging and one for USB & HDMI or use a hub that has power pass-through.

Comment: I understand. I was in fact thinking if the power pass-through would be mandatory.. probably it would be better